# Crear repositorio en bitbucket y hacer el git push

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

he creado un proyecto en local de php y quiero subirlo a bitbucket , en bitbucket tengo el proyecto creado pero solo tengo la rama master , me gustaria crear una rama develop y trabajar sobre ella, los comandos que he hecho han sido los siguientes. Entiendo que la rama master la deberia tener para cuando tengo una versión estable desde develop hacer un checkout a master , no?

Para ello he usado estos pasos

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "commit inicial"
git remote add origin https://miusuario@bitbucket.org/usuario/prueba1.git
git push origin master
```

> 1-Iniciar repositorio
>   2-Añadir todos los archivos
>   3-Commit inicial
>   4-Vincular el repositorio 
>   5- Este comando de "git push origin master" , no tengo  claro lo que hace y si debo hacerlo asi.

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dices que has creado el proyecto en bitbucket pero entiendo que no lo has clonado aún. Así que el primer paso debería ser clonar el repositorio.

```
git clone https://tu_usuario@bitbucket.org/tu_usuario/tu_repositorio /carpeta_destino
```

A continuación sigues los siguientes pasos:

- mueves tus archivos a `carpeta_destino`
- `git checkout -b develop` para crear la rama `develop`
- `git add [fichero1] [fichero2] ...` para añadir los archivos del proyecto al control del repositorio
- `git commit -m"Mensaje del commit"` para hacer el commit
- `git push origin develop` Para subir los cambios de la rama a bitbucket

Y ya está, con eso deberías tener los cambios subidos a bitbucket.

En cuanto a lo de la rama *master* ... nadie te va a obligar a trabajar de una forma determinada... pero yo personalmente prefiero crear una rama por cada funcionalidad que pretendo añadir a la aplicación para, posteriormente, llevar esos cambios a `master`. De esa forma consigo aislar los cambios de cada funcionalidad en ramas diferentes... que luego pueden fusionarse o no dependiendo de cómo evolucionen.

Es decir, si no es necesario, yo evitaría crear una rama `develop` paralela a `master`.

Answer (score 1):

Para ver las ramas existentes utiliza.

```
git branch
```

Si sólo tienes la rama de *master* te debería aparecer un

```
* master
```

Para crear la nueva rama (development) y luego posicionarte en ella, usa.

```
git checkout -b development
```

que es un atajo de

```
git branch development
git checkout development
```

Si quieres revisar las ramas, puedes volver a ejecutar el comando `git branch` y te aparecerán las ramas existentes y la recién creada.

```
git branch
* development
master
```

ahora muestra que estás sobre la nueva rama *development*.

Luego haz lo siguiente para mandar el contenido a la nueva rama.

```
git push origin development
```

Y te aparecerá algo como

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@repositorio
 * [new branch]      development -> development
```

En resumen.

```
git checkout -b development
git push origin development
```

Answer (score 1):

valida primero los archivos que has cambiado para eso lo haces con un.

```
git status
```

para que puedas cambiarte de rama primero tienes que hacer un commit.

```
git add . && git commit -m "commit inicial"
```

para crear la rama que quieres "develop", usa este comando, con el la creas y te pasas de una vez a la rama creada.

```
git checkout -b "develop"
```

luego coloca los archivos desde la master con

```
git push origin master
```